# Date RegularExpression does NOT work on FireFox

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-\/](0[1-9]|1[012])[-\/](19|20)\d\d$
```

in firefox 33.02, `10/10/2014` works, but `10-10-2014` will NOT work.

however in chrome both `10/10/2014` and `10-10-2014` work.

Why?

EDIT:

I figured out that it's not the expression that's invalid, but probably something in MVC

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Field is required")]
[RegularExpression(@"^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-\/](0[1-9]|1[012])[-\/](19|20)\d\d$", ErrorMessage = "Date is incorrect")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime BevBday { get; set; }
```

cshtml:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BevBday)
```

Using this, in Firefox it will come up as

> The field BevBday must be a date.

in chrome it will not give the same error.

Comment: okay… I see "c#" tag now. so this is some kind of server code (asp.net?), which generates html/js dynamically? that wasn't obvious from the question originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed it to this, now it works.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime BevBday { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

works for me (testing in web-console of firefox)

```
var re = /^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-\/](0[1-9]|1[012])[-\/](19|20)\d\d$/;
// /^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-\/](0[1-9]|1[012])[-\/](19|20)\d\d$/

re.test('10/10/2014');
// true

re.test('10-10-2014');
// true
```

Comment: Thanks, i updated the question, will this still work for you?